# Лог ошибки Aiozmq

Tags: python, исключения, логирование, zeromq

Запускаю [aiozmq](https://aiozmq.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.0/) серверы и клиенты в функции start():

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        start(loop)
        loop.run_forever()
    except Exception as e:
        log(logger, 'critical', settings.NAME, e.__repr__(), traceback=traceback.format_exc())
    stop()
    loop.close()
```

Периодичски в лог пишется подобное, но прога продолжает работать:

```
2018-03-31 14:47:06,267 CRITICAL Cannot unpack [b'\x00/', b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Cookie: mstshash=Administr\r\n\x01\x00\x08\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiozmq/rpc/rpc.py", line 234, in msg_received
    *pre, header, bname, bargs, bkwargs = data
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 4, got 2)
```

Не могу понять как поймать этот эксепшен для обработки? 
В коде выше, все остальные эксепшены логируются функцией `log()` и ее формат строк другой.

Answer (score 0):

Исключения не останавливают цикл событий. Что происходит с исключением вы можете с помощью своего обработчика определять:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio


def exception_handler(loop, context):
    print('custom exception handler', context['exception'])
    loop.stop()


def start(loop):
    loop.call_later(1, lambda: 1/0)
    loop.call_later(2, lambda: loop.set_exception_handler(exception_handler))
    loop.call_later(3, lambda: 2/0)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    start(loop)
    loop.run_forever()
except Exception as e:
    assert 0, "won't happen"
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Пример вывода:

```
Exception in callback start.<locals>.<lambda>() at ./__main__.py:11
handle: <TimerHandle when=42.427967554 start.<locals>.<lambda>() at ./__main__.py:11>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/events.py", line 125, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "./__main__.py", line 11, in <lambda>
    loop.call_later(1, lambda: 1/0)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
custom exception handler division by zero
```

Traceback от первого исключения напечатан с помощью обработчика по умолчанию. Последняя строчка относится ко второму исключению и напечатана в новом `exception_handler()`.